# SQL Server: Update Zips, see if zips exist, Update Carrier to correspond with Zips

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, zipcode, carrier

```
vcAccountNum | iZone | vcZipStart | vcZipEnd | vcCarrier1 
| vcCarrier2 | vcTerminal1 | vcTerminal2 | DAS
```

I want to see if a zip exists out of 6000 zips. The `zipEnd` and `zipStart` are the same. If the ABC Carrier is either/or `vcCarrier1` or `vcCarrier2` then `vcTerminal1` and/or `vcTerminal2` need to be updated with a new code, example JFK.

I also need to flag `DAS` Y or N depending on the zip.

I am thinking of using IN for all of the zips.

I have to do this every so often. Looking at a way to make a SP or just get this one done without spending a day on it.

Thank You,

Answer (score 0):

I think you are searching for a query like this:

```
UPDATE yourTable
SET
    vcTerminal1 = CASE WHEN vcCarrier1 = 'ABC Carrier' THEN 'NewCode' ELSE vcTerminal1 END,
    vcTerminal2 = CASE WHEN vcCarrier2 = 'ABC Carrier' THEN 'NewCode' ELSE vcTerminal2 END,
    DAS = CASE WHEN 'zip Code' = 'Depeneds' THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END
WHERE
    'zip Code' BETWEEN vcZipStart AND vcZipEnd
```

Comment: I am a bit confused. I tried to rewrite this as a SELECT other than UPDATE so I could test it. I keep getting errors. Obviously I changed 'ABC Carrier" to what was need and ect...

Comment: You can give us some sample data and expected output to help you more ;).